# Tycho: Parent POM needs to list plug-ins included in my feature?

Tags: maven, tycho

I am transitioning from using Buckminster to build an Eclipse product to Tycho. I've mavenized my plug-ins and features and have a question:

I created a parent feature with a POM that references my features and plugins. I don't know if I am doing this correctly, but I find that I need to add all features and plugins as modules. So if I have `pluginA`, `pluginB` and `feature1` that includes `pluginA` and `pluginB`, I add all three to parent POM. This is a bit strange to me, because in Buckminster I had to reference only `feature1` and it would get its dependencies based on the `feature.xml` file.

I am doing something wrong in my Tycho builds, or is this how it's suppose to work?

Comment: Does your feature POM have `dependencies` to the plug-ins by their Maven GAV? This is not needed if the plug-ins are anyway aggregated by the parent POM.

Comment: @oberlies Sorry, I am still new to Maven terminology. What do you mean by feature POM? Is that POM in my main feature that references other features that in included in parent POM?

Comment: With feature POM, I meant the `pom.xml` next to the `feature.xml` of your "parent feature".

Answer (score 0):

A Tycho build is driven by Maven, i.e. Maven first determines which modules should be part of the build reactor, and then Tycho builds the modules. Therefore, you'll need an [aggregator POM](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) that tells Maven about the list of artifacts to be built.

Comment: So you are saying that I need to list all plugins and features that should be build, rather than using OSGi type dependency resolution where I say that featureA is my main feature so get all it's dependencies? This is my parent POM by the way: http://pastebin.com/U8J180J0